# How to find the same email address with Sublime Text?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a file with lots of email address like following:

```
a@email.com
1email@email.com
c13098Z@gmail.com
08098@yahoo.com
jfdsalkasf@yahoo.com
asfouafj@msn.com
// more
```

Only one email address per line, I want to find the same email address using Sublime Text.

I tried `^(.+)$[\r\n](^\1$[\r\n]{0, 1})+`, it only works after `SORT LINES`. Is there any other way without `sort lines`?

Comment: @j1-lee Done, thanks.

Comment: You want to do it in Sublime Text, in Vim, in both, or in either?

Comment: Maybe `^(.+)(?:\R.*)*?\R\1$`? See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZFCZ8/1).